# certificate for ssl connection does not recognized from cmd

Tags: java, ssl, cmd, certificate, ssl-certificate

I wrote an application that while running connects to SSL address.
I have added the certificate to the key store using the next line in cmd:
`keytool -import -alias cddis-caster.gsfc.nasa.gov 
-keystore "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\security\cacerts" 
-file "D:\projects\Certificates\cddis-caster.gsfc.nasa.gov.crt"`.
The application is running smoothly.

Next i have created a jar file which can be run from cmd.
While running the application from cmd i receive an error while trying to connect to the SSL address, it says it can not find the certificate.
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

While connecting to a non SSL address it runs fine.

How can i solve this problem? where do i have to place the certificate in order to run the executable jar file?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: (1) Are you sure you are running the JDK "private' JRE, or are you just giving the command `java`? The latter normally uses a 'public' JRE, which for j8 is in `\Program Files [(x86)]\java\jre1.8.0_nn` and actually invoked (in PATH) via symlink in `\ProgramData\Oracle\java\javapath`. (2) Are you sure the app is either using the JVM detault truststore (which is `lib/security/cacerts`) or explicitly using that file?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I have used [This](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target) link, it works like a charm.